# Detecting He in a D2 gas sample

Tags: spectroscopy

It would seem possible to detect He in a sample of D2 gas by emission spectroscopy.  I have a quartz ampule (~1cc) of **atmospheric pressure** D2 with possible 1 ppm He reaction products in it.  Could one excite the gas (perhaps by 13 MHz rf) and be able to detect a He (4) line?  Does anyone know of equipment or labs that could do this?

For the present, I'd like to keep the ampule sealed, and the testing to be non-destructive.

Comment: It is 3-He or 4-He in your ampoule? You could try to look for nuclear resonance with He-3. Or with He-4, electrical excitation gives you beautiful and characteristic lines (see [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/atspect.html). Either way, calibrating to an absolute concentration will be a challenge. Are you able to open the ampoule or does it have to remain sealed?

Comment: A quartz ampule I presume? Yes, you can use RF. In fact many labs used to have an old medical Diathermy Machine and a cavity in which to place quartz ampules for just this purpose.